# How to display my hta application name and icon in task manager?

Tags: hta

How to display my hta application name in task manager instead of displaying "Microsoft (R) HTML Application host" when it runs?

Also, how to show an icon in the task manager instead of default hta icon?

Comment: Do you have a `title` tag and `<hta: icon="path_to_ico_file">` in the `head` section? These items are supposed to shown in the Task Manager too (with Win7 at least).

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible when running an hta file as it always runs under mshta.exe.

Add this line to your .hta file `MsgBox document.location.pathname`. It looks normal until you compile it and run it. Then mshta "decompiles" it (decompile is not really an accurate term in this case) into a temporary folder and runs it from there.

The best you can do is use titles and icons for a different look on the taskbar, but in Task Manager it's always going to be mshta.

Comment: I can see the title and the icon of the HTA app in my Task Manager's "Applications" tab, but in "Processes" tab there's always "mshta.exe *32".